# Type Initialization Exception

Tags: c#

i use a class to declare a public static variables

```
 class Variables
{

   public static string AncMotP = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Projects\hanout\WindowsFormsApplication1\mtp.txt");


    static public  float sommeInit = (float)Convert.ToDouble(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Projects\hanout\WindowsFormsApplication1\hanout.txt")), sommeAjout, rest;


}
```

}

When excute the program it show this error [My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea7TD.png)

Comment: This is an english site - aside from the formatting issues in your post, you shouldn't post an image of the error in a different language. If you want to ask this question here, translate the error message and edit your post to tell us what it says in english.

Comment: ...or, at least, accept others' corrections. We're trying to help you.

Comment: Update Error in English

Answer (score 1):

A type initialisation exception is thrown when you cannot create the instance of the Type associated with your class. In your case you are performing a file read to initialise your static variable.

You could move the code to a static constructor wrap it in a try/catch block and set the variable to some meaningful default.

The catch block will also allow you to delve into the exception.